# Android 2.1 Superpad Tablet: can't connect Eclipse ADB to Superpad USB port

Tags: android-emulator

I am developing an Android app for a class I'm taking. I've been using the emulator to date. I know what to see if it runs on the real HW.

My PC runs Windows 7. I downloaded the latest google/Android USb driver. I have enabled the USB Debugging feature on the tablet already. When I plug the tablet  into the PC via USB, the PC doesn't seem to see the tablet at all.
What do I need to do to get these two devices to see one another.

thanks,
wk

Answer (score 1):

HI, I'm using superpad 3, and just have adb connection over ethernet, all you need is type cmd: "connect your.pad.ip" and then Eclipse will see your device.